# Transaction Verification failed. while using different types of states as input and output

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda, smartcontracts

I am facing an issue while creating a Cordapp.
I have two types of states Policy State and Claim State and their respective contracts.
Now I am writing a Claim Flow in which a Policy state will be taken as input and a claim state should be produced as output.

But I am facing this error while doing so-

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection: Contract verification failed: Required com.example.contract.PolicyContract.Commands.Create command, contract: com.example.contract.PolicyContract, transaction: B6F0A0B895B477153530F060B264FE85BAA8F29BA922A546BEC6300A255667C7
```

I am enclosing my Policy Contract, ClaimContract and ClaimFlow-

PolicyContract- https://ideone.com/giz7uX

ClaimContract-https://ideone.com/3GM4UF

ClaimFlow-https://ideone.com/BobTsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `requireSingleCommand`. When you create a transaction with input states, the command that the input state was included within another transaction will load here as well. To solve this use `tx.commandsOfType<YourType>()` or whatever the syntax is. This will not throw an exception.

The exception is due to `single` being called in `requireSingleCommand`.

Comment: Thanks a lot dan. :)